# Which method will be better when multiply 100 with BigDecimal?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Here I have a question when using Java BigDecimal.
Which way will be better when I want to multiply 100 for a object of BigDecimal.

1. multiply 10 twice;
2. movePointRight(2);
3. scaleByPowerOfTen(2);
4. any other way? please show me if there is.

BTW, it will be used for commercial calculation, so I'm considering the precision rather than the speed.

Comment: I would say #2 or #3 -- I suspect the two are pretty much equivalent.

Comment: And I'm not sure why you would ever multiply times 10 twice, vs multiplying by 100 once.

Comment: yeah, good question, I just took it as an example. In fact I have a parameter for decimal control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option 3 is the fastest. Options 1 and 2 are roughly the same (option one being to multiply by ten twice). Multiplying by 100 instead gets up near the speed of option 3.

Here's my test code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class TestingStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        BigDecimal d2 = new BigDecimal(0); // to load the big decimal class outside the loop
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(99);
            d2 = d.movePointRight(2);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("movePointRight: " + (end - start));

        BigDecimal ten = new BigDecimal(10);
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(99);
            d2 = d.multiply(ten).multiply(ten);
        }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("multiply: " + (end - start));

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(99);
            d2 = d.scaleByPowerOfTen(2);
        }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("scaleByPowerOfTen: " + (end - start));
    }

}
```

Of course you could just try the various options yourself in your own code. If you can't measure the difference, then why are you optimizing?

Comment: +1 Used your test harness with my multiplyOneHundred, "multiply: 160",
"multiplyOneHundred: 87",
"scaleByPowerOfTen: 21"

Comment: I feel like it's obligatory to point out your test is [not robust](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-benchmark1/). Using currentTimeMillis, not doing anything with the results so that the compiler is free to refactor everything and BigDecimal class gets loaded inside the first loop.

Comment: Another problem with this benchmark is that it doesn't allow for JVM warmup effects.

Comment: you pointed out a good question.In fact I consider the precision of the calculation rather than the speed.