# What is the difference between BigDecimal movePointRight and scaleByPowerOfTen?

Tags: java, math, bigdecimal

With the following code:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("34.5678");
BigDecimal a = x.movePointRight(3);
BigDecimal b = x.scaleByPowerOfTen(3);
BigDecimal c = x.movePointRight(-3);
BigDecimal d = x.scaleByPowerOfTen(-3);
```

a and b are both 34567.8 and c and d are both 0.0345678.
`a.scale()` and `b.scale` are both 1 and `c.scale()` and `d.scale()` are both 7.

In what circumstances do these two methods produce different results?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `movePointRight` will prevent a negative scale from occurring if it results in one.
- `scaleByPowerOfTen` will not prevent this.

Example code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class BigDecimalScale {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    long base = 12345;
    int scale = 4;

    BigDecimal number = BigDecimal.valueOf(base, scale);
    System.out.println(number);
    BigDecimal pointRight = number.movePointRight(5);
    System.out.println(pointRight + "; my scale is " + pointRight.scale());
    BigDecimal scaleBy = number.scaleByPowerOfTen(5);
    System.out.println(scaleBy + "; my scale is " + scaleBy.scale());
  }
}
```

Result:

```
1.2345
123450; my scale is 0
1.2345E+5; my scale is -1
```

Comment: This answer was posted at the same time as my own, which shows that precision can cause a negative scale too. However the first two lines of this answer succinctly point out the difference.

Comment: Also note that they have different speed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298457/which-method-will-be-better-when-multiply-100-with-bigdecimal

Answer (score 3):

I've found the answer.
If x is declared as

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("34.5678", new MathContext(4));
```

Then a has a scale of 0, but b has a scale of -1.
`a.toString()` gives 34570, `b.toString()` gives 3.457E+4

Comment: Looks like my answer crossed in the post. However it shows a slightly different case, that is where the initial variable is defined with a precision rather than a scale.